# How to solve error related to icon size while submitting the app to appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store, submit

I'm using 57x57 sized app icon in my Application. But while i am submitting Binary to iOS app store, I am getting the following error:

> iPhone/iPad Touch: icon.png: icon dimensions (590x621) don’t meet the size requirements. The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format

Please guide me to solve this error.

Comment: just resize the icon.png to 57x57 pixel

Comment: but i am use 57x57 size image and nt work for me.

Comment: Can you link to the icon? Maybe the file is corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

Visit [the Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html. You can find the details regarding icon size and specification at apple developer portal.

```
512x512 iTunesArtwork.png 
resize 144x144 Icon-72@2x.png # Home screen for "The New iPad"
resize 114x114 Icon@2x.png # Home screen for Retina display iPhone/iPod
resize 72x72 Icon-72.png # App Store and Home screen on iPad
resize 58x58 Icon-Small@2x.png # Spotlight and Settings for Retina display
resize 57x57 Icon.png # Home screen on non-Retina iPhone/iPod
resize 50x50 Icon-Small-50.png # Spotlight on iPad 1/2
resize 29x29 Icon-Small.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all your images that you have in your bundle. Maybe there is some image you forgot. 3 ideas:

1. Your project (in the Project Navigator at left) -> Select Your
   target -> Build Phases -> Copy bundle resources. And then look if
   you    have some file with this size.
2. Check your Info.plist file and check to which files you are referring to as icon files.
3. In the project navigator, if you find the file icon.png, right click    on it, Reveal in Finder, and check to which file it
   is linked, and    what is it size.

Answer (score 0):

The Preview app on your Mac has an Inspector to tell what the size of your png's really is. Check them against your assumed image dimensions, and fix if there's something different.  You could also have Preview save a copy of the png in case there was any anomaly in the original file.

Check your app's plist and make sure you that Xcode is using the icon file(s) that you think it is.